# Rename Features with IF/Else

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, features

I used arcpy.describe to get the shapetype of my features:

`desc = arcpy.Describe(Importpfad)
geometryType = desc.shapeType`

Now i want to add this information at the end of the feature name. It also works perfect:

`Finalname = str(Name)+"_"+ str(geometryType)`

Now the problem: I want to change "_Polygone" into a simple "_p" so that the name is not so long.

I tried different versions using if/else to rename it (with no result):

Update: It worked

`#Get FeatureType
desc = arcpy.Describe(Importpfad)
Name = desc.Name
geometryType = desc.shapeType
if geometryType == 'Polygon':
    geometryType = 'f'
elif geometryType == 'Point':
    geometryType = 'p'
elif geometryType == 'Polyline':
    geometryType = 'l'`

`#Finalname
Finalame = str(Herkunft) +"_"+ str(Kriterium) +"_"+str(geometryType)`

Comment: The line `Name = desc.Name` changes (or redefines) `Name` as it is defined in the line `Name = str(Herkunft) +"_"+ str(Kriterium)` It changes `Name` to the actual name of your feature class as it would appear in the table of contents.

Comment: If you are asking how to rename the actual feature class use Rename tool (http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/rename.htm) . You are only changing the value of the Finalname variable

Comment: @BERA: acually i dont want to rename it - i want to create a output name ending with a "_P" for point and "_A" for polygone....

Comment: @reevesii: but ist the line `Name = desc.Name` nessesary?

Comment: and if you `print Finalname` (or Finalame, as you spell it) what is the output?

Comment: @BERA: in The moment: HerkunftXY_KriteriumXY_Polygone

Comment: @reevesii: thank you - it worked - i just needed changed the finalname. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I use `A` for polygon, or area, because both point and polygon begin with p. I also added the `desc.name`.

```
desc = arcpy.Describe(PathToFC)
Name  = desc.Name
geometryType = desc.shapeType
if geometryType == 'Polygon':
    geometryType = 'a'
elif geometryType == 'Point':
    geometryType = 'p'
elif geometryType == 'Polyline':
    geometryType = 'l'            

Finalname = str(Name)+"_"+ str(geometryType)
```

Comment: @reevesii: I tried and updated my script above. No results.

Comment: @BERA: I have no clue what a dictionary is. I tried exactly what you wrote - no result as well

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use python built-in  [index](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings)  function for the string. select first and second characters of string based on the index.

```
geomtype = str(geometryType)
goemname = geomtype[0:1]+geomtype[-1]
Finalname = str(Name)+"_"+ goemname
```

Use two letters (the first and the last letters to distinguish "Polygon" and "Polyline" words. It's very important because other users  can understand easily the shape type of layers.

Comment: Thanks - but then i can also stay with the woring "Polygone" and "Point" - no one will understand Pn and Pe